# Exchange Online push notification subscription unable to perpetuate

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have inherited from a colleague who left a system module that integrates with Exchange Online in Office 365. Essentially what this module does is interact with with the remote Exchange service via [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567(v=exchg.150).aspx); [subscribe for push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee356425(v=exchg.80).aspx) on changes in a user's calendar.

Change events do get posted to our web service and that is fine. And based on the *frequency* parameter we defined, the status checks messages also get posted on expected intervals, [as per description about the subscription keep-alive behaviour](http://www.thesoftwaregorilla.com/2010/04/exchange-web-services-subscriptions-and-notifications/).

The problem is, in observation, the subscription does not perpetuate despite responding with SubscriptionStatusType.OK to keep it ongoing. We never send SubscriptionStatusType.Unsubscribe since there is no error condition found in notification in messages. It seems to only last 9 to 14 hours before the Exchange service stops sending any status checks or change notification messages. When we make subscriptions from two separate web servers (different notification callback URLs), their subscriptions seem to die out around the same time.

Haven't found any clues that would cause the Exchange service to cancel/expire our subscriptions. What other conditions might contribute to this premature unsubscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange will "lose" subscriptions on a fairly regular basis, especially in the O365 environment because mailboxes are continually being shuffled onto different servers in order to load balance the entire ecosystem.  Even in an on-prem Exchange you can lose subscription if a CAS restarts.  Unfortunately to build a reliable app, you have to check periodically that you heard from Exchange via some kind of notification or heartbeat.

Comment: Where did you source this implementation detail from? So it appears until Microsoft improves the persistence of subscriptions to be CAS agnostic, we're screwed.

Comment: This has been learned from years of writing and supporting an application that uses push (and now streaming) notifications.  I've worked with MS Support on numerous issues in this area.  I'm not sure it's a question of waiting for MS to change the CAS, nor would I necessarily consider us "screwed," as much challenged to deal with unreliability in a networked world.